# Couldn't open wallet wrong device status Ledger

Tags: ledger

When trying to access my wallet on Ledger I get an error message. I'm using GUI version 0.17.1.7. Error message= Couldn't open wallet wrong device status: 0x6e00(sw_cla_not_supported), Expected 0x9000(sw_ok), mask 0xffff

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please make sure that your firmware is upgraded to v1.6.1, your Monero GUI to v0.17.1.8, and your Ledger Monero App to 1.7.4/1.7.5. Additionally, make sure to close the Ledger Live manager and open the Ledger Monero App. Thereafter, the issue should resolve itself.

Comment: I have the same Problem since I use the 0.17.2.1 Monero GUI.
Ledger Monero APP is the lastest with 1.7.5. Ledger Live is closes. Ledger Monero App opened.
But still same error.